# Using chrome driver for find element

Tags: c#, bots

I am using driver chrome for click button programmatically but I can not access to chrome.exe

```
static IWebDriver driverchromeDriver;
    public void chromeDriver()
    {
        driverchromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
        driverchromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driverchromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("qwe");
        driverchromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
    }
```

but it shows this problem :
Additional information: The file C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it expects a file named "chromedriver.exe" in the directory you specify in the constructor. "chromedriver.exe" seems to be hard-coded in `ChromeDriver`. If you download chromedriver.exe at the link you provided and change the code to:

```
driverchromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"path where chromedriver.exe is located");
```

It should work.

As a side note: `chromedriver.exe` is not the same as Chrome. Chrome is the actual browser and `chromedriver.exe` is the actual WebDriver for automated testing. So I would not put `chromedriver.exe` in the same directory as Chrome.

Comment: Do you mean this file : \WebsiteOpening\bin\Debug\WebDriver.dll ?

Comment: WebDriver.dll is Selenium. Selenium does not support chrome out-of-the-box. Every browser vendor creates their own driver where Selenium can communicate with. That is what chromedriver.exe is doing. That is why you need to download it from the url you posted and let `ChromeDriver` know where to find it